# making query using class method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to use this way,

models.py

```
class Father(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(...)

      def last_child_age(self):
          children = self.child.order_by('-pk')
          if len(children) > 0:
             return find_Year(datetime.datetime.now()-children[0].birth_day) 
          return -1


class Child(models.model):
          father = models.ForeignKey(Father, related_name='child')
          birth_day = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def get_old_fathers(request):
     father_list = Father.objects.filter(last_child_age__gte=15)
```

Returns:

```
   Cannot resolve keyword
```

error.

What is the correct way of making this query other than iterating one by one.

Comment: Why do you want to do from method, just make it a property like `name` , and use it?

Comment: inside last_child_age, i have a lot of coding. How is that possible?

Comment: How is Child related to the Father class? Is it a foreign key relation?

Comment: Child has a foreign key: father to Father

Comment: What's the code inside last_child_age function? I'm sure there can be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I've added Child and last_child_age code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cant make queries using model class method (passing function to filter) in Django**

If you need list of `Father` objects which have childs with age > 15 years:

```
d = datetime.date.today()
father_list = Father.objects.filter(
    child__birth_day__lte=datetime.date(d.year-15, d.month, d.day))
```

Without adding flags to Child you can decide which is last (youngest) by making subqueries to child table. Annotation with max birthday (last son -> bigger birth_day date) can help. Try this query (im not test it):

```
from django.db.models import Max
father_list = Father.objects.annotate(max_birthday=Max('child__birth_day')
    ).filter(max_birthday__lte=datetime.date(d.year-15, d.month, d.day))
```

Comment: That's ok. What to add if I want to get list of fathers whose last (!) child's age > 15 years.

Comment: This is close. I am trying to go ahead without adding a field because I have more than 200K fathers and more than million children in DB right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted your Child model and last_child_age code, but something like this should work:

```
Child.objects.filter(age__gte=15).prefetch_related('father')
```

Comment: i've added missing part

Answer (score 0):

`last_child_age` is a method, not a column. ORM queries generate SQL, and SQL don't know zilch about your models methods - how would the SQL database call back on your Python code ?

Comment: ok, but, is there any way to go ahead without iterating one by one?